# Unity move Vector3 position with transform

Tags: unity, rotation, transformation

How can I move a new Vector3 position with a Transform? Like the transform is the parent the vector.

[image]

Example if I want to push the x position for example by 10 value and I rotate the transform its push in world coordinate but I want to push by the rotation too.

```
    void Update () {
    temp = transform.Find("Transform").position;
    temp = new Vector3(temp.x + 10.0f, temp.y, temp.z);

    Debug.DrawLine(transform.Find("Transform").position, temp);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what the `transform.TransformPoint` method does: takes a position in local coordinates and transforms it to world coordinates as though it were a child of the transform.

So you can do something like this:

```
// First, transform the point into a local offset.
Vector3 localSpacePoint;

public void SetFollowingPoint(Vector3 worldSpacePoint) {
     localSpacePoint = transform.InverseTransformPoint(worldSpacePoint);
}

// Then move your transform, and get the new position with:

public Vector3 GetFollowingPoint() {
     return transform.TransformPoint(localSpacePoint);
}
```

You'll notice there are also `transform.[Inverse]TransformVector/Direction`, too. These are for...

- **Direction**: things that should be affected by rotation, but not scale or translation (eg. a heading direction)
- **Vector**: things that should be affected by rotation and scale, but not by translation (eg. the relative offset between two objects that move together)
- **Point**: things that should be affected by rotation, scale, and translation (eg. positions on your object, like attachment points)